# An android application that chooses photo from gallery and uploads into the firebase batabase

Tags: java, android

Like I said in my title I am trying to learn to use databases in android application. So I thought of creating a sample application that takes photos from gallery and uploads the image into the firebase database. However, my application collapses itself after I select a photo from gallery.

Here is my android manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.trump.demo_cameraapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Here is my layout file, activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2">

    </ImageView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose Photo!"
        android:textColor="@color/Blue"
        android:id="@+id/chooseButton"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text = "Upload Photo!"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:id="@+id/uploadButton"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have the following lines of code in MainActivity

```
package com.example.trump.demo_cameraapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 0;
    public static int count = 0;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private StorageReference storage;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    public static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 2;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Here, we are making a folder named picFolder to store
        // pics taken by the camera using this application.


       mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


       Button choose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chooseButton);
        choose.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        upload.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void showFileChooser(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select an image"),PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null && data.getData()!=null) {
            Log.d("ResultOK", String.valueOf(RESULT_OK));
            Log.d("CameraDemo", "Pic saved");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
            mProgressDialog.show();
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            StorageReference filepath = storage.child("images").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>(){

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId() == R.id.chooseButton){
            showFileChooser();


        }else if(view.getId() == R.id.uploadButton){


        }

    }
}
```

I have not yet written codes to upload the image on firebase database. All I am trying to do right now is to display the image I picked from gallery in the imageview of my app. However, like I said before it's not displaying anything right now and as soon as I choose some photo from gallery it collapses. Any help regarding the issue would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no issue with your image picker code, what i found a problem is that you are using mProgressDialog without initializing it in the onCreate() method. So what is recommend is that you first initialize mProgressDialog object in your onCreate() method right after you the initialization of mImageView. And i hope that your application will not collapse now.

Comment: Sorry that did not change anything.

Comment: Can u please show the error message (Crash message) you are getting so that we can investigate further for your problem.